# How to make alarm ring to the set time event after device is switched off and switched on?

Tags: java, android

I've created alarm for each event in calendar while created. It works fine. Now if i set an event for 6pm and if i switch off and switch on the device, the alarm is ringing suddenly when the device is switched on. the alarm is not ringing for the event set time. My code for OnBootReceiver as follows:

```
@Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
  {
      AlarmManager mgr=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
      Intent i=new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
      PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, ap.id1,i, 0);
      mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),PERIOD,pi);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all save that timings in one databse

call a broad cast reveiver class like below

use below code in manifest file

```
<receiver android:name=".main.SampleOnBootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

in above code `SampleOnBootReceiver` is acalss which extends from `BroadcastReceiver`.
in that class u take alaram time from saved databse and set the alaram

Comment: Hi, your solution is correct. I have already given this code in my manifest file. But doesn't work.